# SMTP: Which IP should I monitor?

Tags: smtp, blacklist, blacklist-prevention

I use a relay server to deliver external mails. I use relay server's IP in SPF record. But I'm not sure about blacklist monitoring/checking. Should I check main server's IP or relay's IP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your design, your relay server will be the one making a direct connection to remote mail servers. Therefore whichever public ip your relay uses should be the one seen (and checked and possibly reported) by the remote server(s).

Comment: @dyassny: rats, beaten by 2 mins :-)

Comment: easy pickings ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should monitor the relay's IP - if this is the MTA doing the actual delivery, then delivery will fail if it gets into RBL/PBL